# clicking button doesn't execute the function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, local-storage, addeventlistener

I have a problem with toggling menu. It works in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox. When I click on a button, it just doesn't execute the function.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

I also checked it in jsfiddle and it works there in FF but not in my real app.

```js
var toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle-button");


toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('open'); 
});
```

```html
<button class="toggle-button">
  button
</button>
```

edit:
I found that the problem is caused by cookie consent function:

```
(function () {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieconsent")) {
        document.body.innerHTML +=
            '\
        <div class="cookieconsent" style="position:fixed;padding:20px;left:0;bottom:0;background-color:#000;color:#FFF;text-align:center;width:100%;z-index:99999;">\
            This website uses cookies. Read more\
            <a class="privacy-policy__link" href="/privacy-policy/index.html">here</a>.\
            <a id="consent" href="#" >I agree.</a>\
        </div>\
        ';
        document.querySelector("#consent").onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector(".cookieconsent").style.display = "none";
            localStorage.setItem("cookieconsent", true);
        };
    }
})();
```

When I hide this function, the menu works, but I still don't know what is wrong in this function that it prevents click event from working in Firefox.

edit 2:
Now I see, that problem is actually in all browsers. Menu doesn't work untill I agree for cookies and refresh browser.

Comment: Well what is different? Where is the script located? Are there errors in the console? My guess, you are looking for the element before it exists on the page.

Comment: Highly unlikely. Perhaps you have some framework like Bootstrap or some form field prettyfier? There is nothing in your code that should not work in FX

Comment: it works in FF!

Comment: @mplungjan in that case, you are overwriting your event handler somewhere or something prevent the click event to trigger.

Comment: @Reza it is not my question. I know it is something like that. I already suggested that

Comment: @Reza OP said: _I also checked it in jsfiddle and it works there in FF but not in my real app._

Comment: @mplungjan without the code, it's difficult to say more

Comment: @Reza Please [read my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815993/clicking-button-doesnt-execute-the-function-in-firefox#comment111082953_62815993)

Comment: Ok, I found where is a problem. It's something with cookies, because when I hided the function for cookie consent, it started to work in Firefox.